# React Native Animation Resize

Tags: animation, react-native, lottie

React Native Animation does not scale. Animation is bigger. My code:

```
import { DangerZone } from 'expo';
const { Lottie } = DangerZone;
```

Styles:

```
animationContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',z
},
```

View:

```
<Lottie
        ref={(animation) => {
          this.animation = animation;
        }}
        resizeMode="contain"
        loop={Boolean(true)}
        style={{
          width: 300,
          height: 30,
          backgroundColor: '#ccc',
        }}
        source={this.state.animation}
      />
```

[App screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brAZh.png)

I don`t know why this does not work. Please help me